# FFmpeg - possible to select X frames every N frames?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to select 10 frames out of every 100 frames of video and write that to a new output.

In a 1000 frame video, I want the output to only include frames:

1-10, 100-110, 200-210... etc.

Is there a way to do this with FFmpeg?  I have tried various combinations of the select filter, but it seems to only be able to select 1 frame every N frames.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
select='lt((mod(n\,100)\,10)'
```

If you are creating a new video, you may want to add

```
setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)
```

after the select.